# Will this algorithm always work?

Tags: ti-basic

So I'm writing a TI-BASIC algorithm for my calculator that does ratios.  Here is the code:

```
Disp "GIVE ONE NUMBER"
Prompt A
Disp "GIVE A SECOND NUMBER"
Prompt B
While fPart(A)≠0 or fPart(B)≠0
A*10->A
B*10->B
End
gcd(A,B)->C
Disp A/C
Disp B/C
```

It seems to work in most cases.  Are there any flaws/corner cases of this code that I have not noticed? Thanks.

Comment: I also like the name.  The Fight Club movie was terrible though.

Comment: When I saw this tagged `ti-basic` my mind instantly rushed back to my childhood TI-99/4A with its `CALL SOUND` and Parsec.  Was disappointed to see this was a graphing calculator post.  Sigh.

Comment: @Someone All the ways you wish you could be, that's me. I look like you wanna look, I screw like you wanna screw, I am smart, capable, and most importantly, I am free in all the ways that you are not.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, but there is an even cooler way to do it with no loops.

```
Disp "GIVE ONE NUMBER"
Prompt A
Disp "GIVE A SECOND NUMBER"
Prompt B
1/fPart(A)->F
A*F->A
B*F->B
1/fPart(B)->F
A*F->A
B*F->B
gcd(A,B)->C
Disp A/C
Disp B/C
```

Comment: So you definitely think that both will work? Also I'm guessing the advantage of your algorithm is it's faster?

Comment: I don't know if it's faster. Mine has the potential for rounding issues with division. Both solutions should work though.

Comment: Wait a sec.  This won't work if the original numbers are integers

Comment: @someone haha oops, I guess there needs to be a check before the division so that it's not dividing by 0.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to add the integer checking myself

Comment: Just check at the beginning and if yes skip the 1/fpart stuff and go right to gcd, correct?

Comment: @Someone You'd have to check before each 1/fpart, it's possible that the first fpart will make both values integers. ex: 1.5,2.5 -> 3,5 -> division by 0.

Comment: Ah very true.  You know, maybe for the time being I will use my own algorithm :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work and so will Jean-Bernard Pellerin's answer, but to best clean it up:

```
Input "GIVE ONE NUMBER",A
Input "GIVE A SECOND NUMBER",B
1/fPart(A)->F
A*F->A
B*F->B
1/fPart(B)->F
A*F->A
B*F->B
gcd(A,B)->C
Disp A/C
Disp B/C
```